# black screen while embedding youtube video using react native youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

only audio is coming not video . earlier it was working for many months and suddenly it automatically showing black screen

```
import YouTubeIframeModule from 'react-native-youtube-iframe'

 <YouTubeIframeModule  
         height={220}
         width={'100%'}
        onFullScreenChange={onFullScreenChange}
        initialPlayerParams={{controls:true,}}
        play={playing}
        videoId={props.videoid}
        onChangeState={stateHandler}
        ref={r=>playerRef=r}
        webViewProps={{
            allowsInlineMediaPlayback: false,
            androidLayerType:'hardware',
            androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled:false,
            mixedContentMode:'always',
            javaScriptEnabled:true,
            domStorageEnabled:true,
            startInLoadingState:true,
            originWhitelist:["*"],
            style:{flex:1},
        

        }}
       
        forceAndroidAutoplay

      />
```

Comment: manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" fixes the issue

Comment: Amesh it worked for me as well.